# Android NDK build to support all available devices

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android

I am using in my project both java files and native c++ code. I would like to make the app available for all devices and hardware (API lvl >= 15). I am also using OpenCV4Android both in java and my native c++ if that matters. I'm not quite sure if my current configuration is sufficient to support all available hardware:

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include C:/OpenCV4Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := myNativeLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myNativeLib.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have tested this configuration on a few devices and it seems to work but doesn't `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a` narrow down the supported devices to only those with `armeabi-v7a`, or actually every device will be able to run it? Maybe I should insert `APP_ABI := all` as mentioned here? https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html

It is very important to me to make the app responding and working for all devices possible.

Comment: To support all platforms you should use APP_ABI := all and for api 15 use APP_PLATFORM := android-15

Comment: Thanks, indeed I totally missed the APP_PLATFORM attribute but I'm a bit suspicious about APP_ABI? If setting it to all makes automagically our app available to all hardwares, why isn't APP_ABI set to all by default then?

Comment: If you set it to "all" it will create a binary for every platform meaning the size of  your app will be larger

Comment: oh I see! That explains a lot, Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, the size of my package rose from 25 MB to 60MB after setting APP_ABI to all. That's a bit too much but do you happen to know what are most widely used hardwares currently? You could post an answer and I would accept it then ^^

Comment: The most widely used for arm possessors is "armeabi-v7a" , and for new 64 bit possessors is "arm64-v8a", for x86 processors is "x86" and for x86 64 bit possessors is "x86_64".
The "armeabi-v7a" and "x86" will be supported on the most platforms including the new 64 bits platforms.
For more info read here under "APP_ABI" section: http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support all platforms you should use `APP_ABI := all` 
. For API 15 use `APP_PLATFORM := android-15`.
Pay attention that the more platforms you will support the larger your apk file will be, since it will create a binary for each supported platform in your APK.

Comment: with bundling sizes can be reduced significantly. include that in your answer